# Django + markdown fail to render my code on my server

Tags: django, markdown

Django + markdown fail to render my code on my server,but it's right on my pc.

this is on my pc
[image]

```html
<div class="codehilite">
<pre><span></span>``
<span class="kn">import</span> 
<span class="nn">numpy</span> 
<span class="kn">as</span> 
<span class="nn">np</span>
```

this is on my server
[image]

```html
`<pre class="codehilite"><code>import numpy as np</code></pre>`
```

this is my css

```css
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/monokai.css' %}" />
```

this is my body

```html
{% extends "./blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load custom_markdown %}
<div class="posts">
  <h1>{{BlogPost.title}}</h1>
  {{BlogPost.body|custom_markdown}}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

this is my markdown settings

```html
import markdown
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
register = template.Library()  #自定义filter时必须加上
@register.filter(is_safe=True)  #注册template filter
@stringfilter  #希望字符串作为参数
def custom_markdown(value):
    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(value,
                                       extensions = ['markdown.extensions.fenced_code', 'markdown.extensions.codehilite'],
                                       safe_mode=False,
                                       enable_attributes=False))
```

thanks for everybody's help